# Emulator : Allow App to access device location by default

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run automation, is there some way where the App is allowed to access device location by default.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can store last location in shared preference and use that whenever you want. But for the current location i think it cant happen without user granting permission.